# Why isn't my Javascript being included properly?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I placed a file under the Javascript assets here:  `assets/javascripts/Problem.js`

I went to my view and pasted:`<%= javascript_include_tag "Problem" %>`

Which yielded this on my page: `<script src="/assets/jquery.ui.touch-punch.min.js?body=1"></script>`

Which links to an empty file - which is why the Javascript is not being loaded in ofc. What's going on here?

Comment: Did you add it to your application.js file?

Comment: Could you explain what that means @CWitty? I didn't find any reference to that in the docs. And If anything, I figured it would be covered by the line `//require_tree .`

Comment: Sorry you're correct about that. Did you add that include to your view or the layout itself?

Comment: I added the include tag to the layout itself

Comment: Weird it looks like it should be fine. Have you ran rake assets:precompile before? I have had that cause issues with loading new assets. If you have try a rake assets:clean